# Database Design - Is redundancy better than adding more relationship?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Hi I wonder which one of these database designs is better:

I have Shopping db, it has two tables: `Categories` and `Brands`. Both of those tables have the columns: `name`, `description`, and `image_url`.

So is it okay to keep the duplicate column? Or should I create a table that stores those information?

To visualize it better, here's a chart

The redundant one

```
| CATEGORIES    |    | BRANDS        | 
| - name        |    | - name        |
| - description |    | - description |
| - image_url   |    | - image_url   |
```

or adding a new table?

```
| CATEGORIES    |    | INFORMATIONS  |      | BRANDS        | 
|               |--->| - name        |<-----|               |
| - info_id     |    | - description |      | - info_id     |
                     | - image_url   |
```

Thanks

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason to the contrary, normalisation (the second approach) is almost always better. Read more on Wikipedia article on [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will the second one be slower?

Comment: Yes, but to an inconsequential degree. (Assuming your indices are good; your example is simple enough that it can't be messed up, as all foreign keys point to the primary key, and primary key is always indexed.)

Comment: Oops - I don't think I understood your question properly. If you have category names and brand names, and not simply shared `names` field, two different tables actually work better - again, unless you have a good reason to the contrary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will keep two separate tables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case it's really NOT the same information. It's category_name, category_description, brand_name and brand_description.

Creating a table to keep generic information about many things is a bad idea.

When it comes to the discussion about (de)normalisation it's generally considered a better design to normalise data and I would start with such a design. As your data evolves and grows it might be necessary to de-normalise some tables as the data retrieval can be faster at the cost of storage space and risk of loosing data consistency.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will keep the first structure